# Is it more usable to display information in a table-like display?

Tags: tables, readability, tooltips

I am trying to display information about the last time a remark has been changed.
For this I have to display the Author, the region, the date and time. This information will appear in a tooltip on mouseover. (I can't write it inline because my application is old and lacks space and I have to do it on mouseover)
Context looks like this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frCPq7.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

I am struggling to know what kind of display should be the most readable. So far I can think of 2 displays:

[image: Tabular display]
The tabular way

[image: Plain language]
Or the plain language way

There may be other alternatives available by mixing font size and styling.
So my question is: Which one of this two alternatives fit the best for a novice user? which one fits the best for an expert user ? (who uses the functionality on a daily basis)

And do you have any other idea that could be more usable?

Comment: I think more context is required to answer this question. Both are readable as is. We need to know more about where will this be used, what other content is this going to be surrounded by, what task is the user trying to accomplish etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the plain language way is more readable, because you're reading it in a natural way as if it's a sentence. But that could be entirely my own preference. It should fit within your application. It should fit the tone.